# Hadoop: How to make several users to be able to write?

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs

I have a hadoop cluster that we use (several friends). We do not want to enforce permission check, we are only learning. If I start the process, nobody else can write to directories I have created.

What is the best way to handle permission in such  a case?

Comment: give full permission to /user/{yourDIR}
Or add all users into a group & and give permission based on group

Comment: How do you do either of your approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled persmission for now. If any other better solution, I will mark it as an answer.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```